# JavaFX menubutton throws exception

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm using MenuButton in fxml to switch between tabs. The problem is, the menubuttons throw exceptions, but if I change it to a simple button, it doesn't. 
Here's my fxml code:

```
 <MenuButton mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="101.0" style="-fx-background-color: #666666;" text="Select menu" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="4">
<items>
<MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToMoney" text="1" />
<MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToWeight" text="2" />
<MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToTemperature" text="3" />
</items>
</MenuButton>
```

In my controller class:

```
 @FXML
    private void switchToMoney() throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("money");
    }

    @FXML
    private void switchToWeight() throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("weight");
    }

    @FXML
    private void switchToTemperature() throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("temperature");
    }
```

and the exception I get:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=64566:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p "C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14\javafx-base-14-win.jar;C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14\javafx-graphics-14-win.jar;D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\projects\proba\target\classes;C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14\javafx-controls-14.jar;C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14\javafx-controls-14-win.jar;C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14\javafx-graphics-14.jar;C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14\javafx-base-14.jar;C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\14\javafx-fxml-14.jar;C:\Users\tarbe\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\14\javafx-fxml-14-win.jar" -m org.alkfejl/org.alkfejl.App
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:222)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.MenuButtonSkinBase.lambda$new$7(MenuButtonSkinBase.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

EDIT: Here's my code of the App class, which extends the Application. 
the App class:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("general"));
        stage.setTitle("Calculator");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work when you add an `ActionEvent event` parameter to the methods?

Comment: I get the same exception with that. The tab switches, with and without ActionEvent parameter, but always throws the exception.

Comment: Did you post the entire stack trace? Or did you post just the first part of the stack trace? If you did **not** post the entire stack trace, please [edit] your question and post the **entire** stack trace you are getting.

Comment: Not sure if I do it correctly, but tried adding 3 of this line: ```MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("blabla");``` and this: ``` MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Select", null, menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3);``` then call ```menuButton.hide();``` in my method. Still throws the exception.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra I gave an answer which provides an MRE, if you're interested in looking into the underlying cause of the problem (related to the `MenuButton`'s scene becoming `null` before it's hidden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error can be reproduced with this minimal example<sup>1</sup>:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MenuButton btn = new MenuButton("Switch...");

    MenuItem item = new MenuItem("To 'Hello, World!'");
    item.setOnAction(
        e -> {
          StackPane root = new StackPane(new Label("Hello, World!"));
          primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(root);
        });
    btn.getItems().add(item);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 500, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:222)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.MenuButtonSkinBase.lambda$new$7(MenuButtonSkinBase.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

There are at least two simple ways to "fix" the NPE:

1. Hide the `MenuButton` before changing the root of the `Scene`.

   ```java
   StackPane root = new StackPane(new Label("Hello, World!"));
   btn.hide();
   primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(root);
   ```

   If you're using FXML then you'll need to inject the `MenuButton` into the FXML controller instance. This is accomplished by giving the element an `fx:id="foo"` attribute in the FXML file and adding an `@FXML private MenuButton foo;` field to the controller. Then you would invoke `foo.hide()` before changing the root of the `Scene`.

   See [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) for more information about FXML.
2. Change the `Scene` of the `Stage` instead of changing the root of the `Scene`.

   ```java
   StackPane root = new StackPane(new Label("Hello, World!"));
   primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
   ```

Both the example and solutions were tested using JavaFX 14.0.1.

---

<sup>1. Note this sort of example is what should be provided by you, in the question.</sup>

Comment: Just edited my question with my app class. Could you take a look at that and explain me why I need these buttons there, once I add them in the fxml file?

Comment: Note sure I understand what you want me to explain. Note I edited my answer to address your use of FXML (see solution #1).

Comment: I mean my App class looks completely different than yours. I don't do anything with buttons there because those are in my fxml file, I just simply load my fxml file, set its root and start it.

Comment: Yes, but the concept is exactly the same. All FXML does is describe an object graph in XML syntax which is then interpreted by an `FXMLLoader` which creates normal, everyday Java objects. My answer simplifies the problem since FXML is irrelevant to the error. You have a `MenuButton`, some `MenuItem`s with an `onAction` handler, and code to switch the root of the `Scene` invoked by said handlers—my example does the exact same thing just without FXML.

Comment: Yes, it's working now.Thanks for your answer and help. The only thing I changed in your #1 answer is, instead of ```@FXML private MenuItem foo``` I used ```@FXML private MenuButton menubutton;``` because the ```hide()``` function throws this error: ```Cannot resolve method 'hide' in 'MenuItem'```. With MenuButton, it works fine.

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant. Thanks for pointing out my mistake; fixed it.

Comment: thanks :) that's part of [JDK-8175358](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175358) fixed in fx15 - or better: in the process of being fixed, turned out we didn't get it completely right ;)

Comment: filed separate [JDK-8244234](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8244234) to not forget .. weird how related itssues tend to bubble up in a rather short time window :)